# How do I create an clickable icon that shows a datepicker with md bootstrap?

Tags: datetime, vue.js, mdbootstrap

I'm working on a Vue.js project with MdBootsrap. I'd like to have an icon displaying a calendar, and when you click on the icon , you'll get a `datepicker` to choose a date from.

How do I implement that?

I've looked at the docs:

and I've tried something like this:

```
  <mdb-date-picker icon="calendar" far :options="today()"></mdb-date-pickler>

<script>
methods : {

today(){
return moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
}
```

The thing I get displayed is a text input field, but in the docs, the input field is changed for a `datepicker` as in my code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In MDB Datepicker the input field is always displayed and is essential for the component's inner structure. You can try hiding it if toggling datepicker with clickable icon is what you're going for:

```html
<template>
<div class="custom-datepicker">
  <mdb-date-picker v-model="date" icon="calendar"/> 
  <p>{{date}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mdbDatePicker } from 'mdbvue';
  export default {
    components: {
      mdbDatePicker
    },
    data() {
      return {
        date: ''
      };
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

.custom-datepicker .mdb-datepicker input {
  display: none;
}

.custom-datepicker .mdb-datepicker i {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: initial;
}
</style>
```

You can always try writing directly to the MDB team on support forum - https://mdbootstrap.com/support/.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this now, but it did not fix it. I had to manually override a class, and changed the width to 85%. Then I made a regular icon with <i><i/>